# How to preselect a single cell in ngx-Datatable?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I want to programmatically select a single cell in a ngx datatable. In the documentation I can find the support for selecting a row:

https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/table/inputs#selected

How can I select a single cell in ngx-datatable, if i have the row number and column number?